# Why does operator<< not work with something returned by operator-?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Here's a small test program I wrote:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {

    public:
    int val;

    A(int _val=0):val(_val) { }

    A operator+(A &a) { return A(val + a.val); }
    A operator-(A &a) { return A(val - a.val); }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &, A &);

};

ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, A &a) {
    out<<a.val;
    return out;
}

int main() {
    A a(3), b(4), c = b - a;
    cout<<c<<endl; // this works
    cout<<(b-a)<<endl; // this doesn't
    return 0;
}
```

I can't seem to get why the line marked "this works" works and the one marked "this doesn't" doesn't. When I try to compile the program with the `cout<<(b-a);` line, here's what I get:

```
[felix@the-machine C]$ g++ test.cpp 

test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:26:13: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::cout << b.A::operator-(((A&)(& a)))’
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.0/../../../../include/c++/4.5.0/ostream:108:7: note: candidates are: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.0/../../../../include/c++/4.5.0/ostream:117:7: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type = std::basic_ios<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.0/../../../../include/c++/4.5.0/ostream:127:7: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.0/../../../../include/c++/4.5.0/ostream:165:7: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.0/../../../../include/c++/4.5.0/ostream:169:7: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.0/../../../../include/c++/4.5.0/ostream:173:7: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(bool) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.0/../../../../include/c++/4.5.0/bits/ostream.tcc:91:5: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(short int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.0/../../../../include/c++/4.5.0/ostream:180:7: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(short unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.0/../../../../include/c++/4.5.0/bits/ostream.tcc:105:5: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.0/../../../../include/c++/4.5.0/ostream:191:7: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.0/../../../../include/c++/4.5.0/ostream:200:7: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long long int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.0/../../../../include/c++/4.5.0/ostream:204:7: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long long unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.0/../../../../include/c++/4.5.0/ostream:209:7: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(double) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.0/../../../../include/c++/4.5.0/ostream:213:7: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(float) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.0/../../../../include/c++/4.5.0/ostream:221:7: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long double) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.0/../../../../include/c++/4.5.0/ostream:225:7: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(const void*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.0/../../../../include/c++/4.5.0/bits/ostream.tcc:119:5: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__streambuf_type*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__streambuf_type = std::basic_streambuf<char>]
test.cpp:18:11: note:                 std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, A&)
[felix@the-machine C]$
```

Quite nasty.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your operator+ returns a temporary object - and in C++ you can't bind temporaries to non-const references. You want:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const A &a) {
```

This is the canonical way to write opertaor<< for streaming - the thing being output should always be passed as a const reference.

Comment: Brilliant. Actually, my lab teacher wasn't able to figure that out.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are not allowing temporaries to be passed to your insertion operator. Change it to:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &, const A &);
...
ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const A &a) {
    out<<a.val;
    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

in the second line,you're asking the compiler to convert from A to A&, but A is a temporary, and that is non-standard behaviour. In the first line c is not temporary so it works.
Changing your operator to

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const A &a)
```

will not only be more correct, but should also be accepted by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a temporary object to `operator<<`, so it needs to take a `const A&`.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const A&)
```

A few other notes:

Always use 'const T&' when passing non-primitive arguments that are not modified.  This allows you to pass temporaries, and indicates that you don't change the parameter.

It's best to mark single argument constructors `explicit`, this prevents you from making accidental temporary objects everywhere, killing your performance.

```
explicit A(int _val=0):val(_val) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

A temporary object is basically considered `const`, so for a reference to bind to it, it has to be a reference to const:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, A const &a) // ...
```

Comment: I am thankful I am not the only one preferring to put all qualifiers after the type. It might seem stupid, but when people interpret `const T&` with `T = char*` as `const char*&`... they don't understand any longer what happens :/

Comment: @Matthieu: Yup -- most English speakers are accustomed to adjectives preceding nouns, but the equivalent in C and C++ doesn't work quite as well. I suspect it seems more natural for people who speak French (for one example) since it uses postfix modifiers.

Comment: What's funny is that French coders do too, because English speaking coders set up the trends :)

Answer (score 0):

The `std::basic_ostream::operator<<` expects const-qualified argument in your use case. Thus, you need to correct the signature of your operator as follows:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, A const& a)
```

By the way, the friendship is redundant because `A::val` is public, thus accessible anyway.